# Webpack Dev Server — Change websocket URL from IP address to "localhost"

Tags: localhost, webpack-dev-server

Currently, Webpack Dev Server is using my IP address as the URL for hot reloading. This is an issue because:

1. I'm using HTTPS and my local certificate is only for "localhost", not my IP address
2. Hot reloading stops working when ever I change networks / IP addresses.

Is there any way to get it to use `localhost` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can actually just do this by changing the [`host` URL in `webpack.config.js`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost) to `localhost`!

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost'
  }
};
```